# Unity Animation Cycle Offset not working

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, offset, cycle

The way I understand it, is if I have an animation that's 30 seconds long and is also a loop, through Cycle Offset I can make this animation start at a time different than second 0. So I could make it start at second 10, go to 30, then back to 0, to 30 and keep looping that way. I have a Game Object, an Animation Controller and an Animation Clip. I set a whole bunch of different values for the Cycle Offset of the Animation by selecting it in the Project Folder and then updated its settings in the Inspector and it does nothing, the animation still starts at second 0 every time, regardless of what value I write in.

Not sure if this helps at all, but I also duplicated my Game Object, Animation Controller and Animation Clip so I actually have 2 of each. I did however, go to my Animator window, to make sure the default state for each Animation Controller is different and it is. I also checked that each object has a different Animation Controller. I honestly don't even think this part matters that much, because even if these were wrong, the animation would at least start from a later point on both game objects when changing the Cycle Offset. What happens though, is basically nothing, the animation just starts from second 0, goes to 30 and loops every time.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, pay attention that Valid range is 0 to 1.0 now:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorState-cycleOffset.html

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the error. I guess entering the value manually for some reason it wasn't working. What I had to do instead is to first drag my cursor over the text "Cycle Offset" to modify the value that way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the same problem but I had a similar one. What I did wrong was I was setting the cycle offset value as frame (if wanted to offset the animation 15 frames I entered 15)

It seems this field must be entered as rate to full cycle. If you want to offset the animation half way you should enter 0.5. This sould offset 15 frames for a 30 frame clip.